# How to keep one of the duplicate rows which doesn't have a Nan in any column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

In this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/panamby/bank-loan-status-dataset) the Loan ID and Customer ID are the same for each duplicate row. Other features are similar too for the duplicate rows except that for some duplicates there are NaNs in one of those rows and no NaNs for the other row. I want to keep the duplicate rows who do not have NaNs but I am unable to do so. Any help on this problem would be appreciated.

I tried this code but it is throwing a MemoryError, I am not sure why:

```
data[(~data.duplicated())|(data.notnull())]
```

I ran into a `MemoryError`.

Sample data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Loan ID':list('aaabbc'),
        'Customer ID':list('hhhttt'),
        'C':[np.nan,8,9,4,2,3],
        'D':[1,np.nan,5,7,1,np.nan]
})

print (data)
  Loan ID Customer ID    C    D
0       a           h  NaN  1.0
1       a           h  8.0  NaN
2       a           h  9.0  5.0
3       b           t  4.0  7.0
4       b           t  2.0  1.0
5       c           t  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: Please include code to show how you set up `data` object and include full error

Comment: Can you please visit the page yourself and show us a snippet how what the data looks like and how you're reading it.

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data - do you need remove missing rows with all data like WebDev's answer or only with duplicated rows and missing data like my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#specify columns for test dupe values and add keep=False for return all dupes, invert by ~
m1 = ~data.duplicated(subset=['Loan ID','Customer ID'], keep=False)
print (m1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool

#check if not missing rows per rows
m2 = data.notnull().all(axis=1)
print (m2)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
#chain conditions by bitwise OR
df = data[m1 | m2]
print (df)
  Loan ID Customer ID    C    D
2       a           h  9.0  5.0
3       b           t  4.0  7.0
4       b           t  2.0  1.0
5       c           t  3.0  NaN

#if need ony one row per duplicated rows by specified columns
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Loan ID','Customer ID'])
print (df)
  Loan ID Customer ID    C    D
2       a           h  9.0  5.0
3       b           t  4.0  7.0
5       c           t  3.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get what you want:

```
print(data.dropna().drop_duplicates(['Loan ID','Customer ID']))
```

Output is:

```
  Loan ID Customer ID    C    D
2       a           h  9.0  5.0
3       b           t  4.0  7.0
```

For more information, refer to [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)